# How come cosets in cokernel of a vector space are defined by $xV$ and not $x + V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

For a linear map $L: V \to W$ (not necessarily finite dim if that even matters, but we can assume this is a bounded linear map between hilbert spaces so we don't have to deal with closures). Why are the cosets in cokernel = $W/im(L)$ defined by  $\bar{w} = wImL$ instead of $w + Im L$? I am trying to understand the equality $ker L^* = cokernel L$, and I am stuck at $(y,L^*x) = (Ly, x) = 0$, this seems to imply the cosets look like $xLy = 0$, but I don't understand why it's not addition $\bar{w} = w + imL$.

Comment: Could you reproduce the statement of the theorem and the proof you're trying to understand in a bit more detail? It looks like this is proving that the kernel of the adjoint is the orthogonal complement of the image of $L$ - which is naturally isomorphic to the cokernel (but of course not technically equal). I'm guessing it actually says something more like "$x \in \operatorname{Ker} L^*$ iff $L^*x = 0$ iff for all $y$, we have $(y, L^*x) = 0$ ..."

Comment: I just realized this is answered by the quotient map.

Comment: If you've solved your problem that's great, but I hope you realise that your question as you asked it didn't really make any sense! It's not clear what you even mean by "$w\operatorname{Im} L$" since you can't multiply vectors, and it's unclear why you think what you wrote means cosets look like that.